# How to update data to a nested array in angular?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, angular8

This is how my JSON file looks like :

```
   {
    "responseCode": 200,
    "responseMessage": "" , 
    "details": "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"sss\",\"status\":\"status 1\",\"active\":true,\"createdAt\":\"Dec 4, 2019, 4:21:46 PM\",\"modifiedAt\":\"Dec 5, 2019, 10:21:09 AM\",\"description\":\"daddddddddddddd\",\"imagePath\":\"imagepath 1\",\"viewCount\":133,\"important\":1}",
    "timestamp": 0
}
```

TS File:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.blog.getBlog(this.id).subscribe((data: {}) => {
  this.blogData = JSON.parse(data['details']);
})
  } 
   updateBlog() {
if(window.confirm('Are you sure, you want to update?')){
  this.blog.UpdateBlog(this.id, this.blogData).subscribe(data => {
    this.router.navigate(['/home/blogger'])
  })
}
}
```

Service File :

```
UpdateBlog(id,blog): Observable<Blog> {
  let body = JSON.stringify(blog);
  console.log(blog)
  return this.http.put<Blog>('blog/' + id, body, this.httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    retry(1),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  )
}
```

I am able to do operations such as Get,delete and create,But unable to update values to the below JSON format.How can i do that?

Below is the postman code under the send option :

```
    PUT /api/blog/3 HTTP/1.1
Host: 13.234.196.102:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJwcmF2aWwiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzU1NDk2NTEsImV4cCI6MTU3NTYzNjA1MX0.j9FBDckN2jfi3-LU5coVGRZfW3wQEBnGpF4MAZ2u_pH6MRdA2KU_xrZTvb1ki9DWTydQ8YTrAgYg2uMkKktn9A
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 7e19e28c-6dde-42e8-b9f2-c1546eb65825,82753b69-39ad-48a5-b5fd-552e07008594
Host: 13.234.196.102:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 160
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

 {

        "name": "sss",
        "description": "Thsh",
        "imagePath": "imagepath 1",
        "status": "status 1",
        "active": true
 }
```

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?

Comment: Http failure response 400 OK, But there is no problem in the backend api

Comment: What technology are you using for your backend? A 400 response might indicate that a PUT request on that resource is not supported, or that your request is malformed.

Comment: Actually i am able to update the values using postman,so i'm not seeing any errors there.I'm using mongoDb.But clearly i can see from the console.log put request is not processing and thus handles the error

Comment: on postman, right below the Send Button, click on Code and paste the content here.

Comment: i have updated the postman code content in the above issue,please check it out.

Comment: What's the output of this line of code in your service file: `console.log(blog)`? You could add also `console.log(body)` to see what are you actually sending to the API.

Comment: In Console.log i'm getting the values that i'm updating in the fields but its not sending to the API and gets 400 error